# show and hide div after submiting an action when checkbox is check and uncheck

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to show  or hide div after submitting an action. so let say I have textarea and I put "example" there then checked the checkbox. after submitting, the "receipt.php" page must display "example" , and if I unchecked the checkbox and submit, the receipt.php page must hide the "example". I tried searching similar to my problem but  I really don't have idea how to solve it.  I have this code so far but i dont have any codes in "receipt.php" since I really don't have idea. pls help me

```
<form method ="POST" action ="receipt.php">
<textarea name ="comment"></textarea><br>
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" value ="1"  >Show this comment in receipt<br>
<input type ="submit" value ="Print">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Html:-

```
<form method ="POST" action ="receipt.php">
    <textarea name ="comment"></textarea><br>
    <input type="checkbox" name="reciept-chk" id="checkbox" value = "1"  >Show this comment in receipt<br>
    <input type ="submit" value ="Print">
</form>
```

In receipt.php:

```
<?php
..//recept.php

 if(isset($_POST['reciept-chk'])){

// Write Code example here

 }

?>
```

If you want to validate it client side before posting your value in receipt.php then 
    you can simply validate by piece of jquery.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#checkbox').change(function(){
    if ($('#checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $("#exampleDiv").show();
    } else {
        $("#exampleDiv").hide();
    }
   });
});
```

Please avoide [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) as it [deprecated in 1.8](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-1.8/)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the server response to recognize if the checkbox was checked unless you have some validation on server side. If using JQuery, you can do this:

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
  $('#your_div').toggle();
});
```

If you want to rely on what your server says you need to return something to your ajax call.
for example {response: true/false}

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code you'll need in your unique PHP file :

```
<form method="POST">
    <textarea name="comment">
        <?php (isset($_POST['checkbox1']) && $_POST['checkbox1'] == '1') ? echo "Example"; : echo ""; ?>
    </textarea>
    <br>
        <label for="checkbox1">Show this comment in receipt</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" name="checkbox1" value="1" />
    <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Print" />
</form>
```

Replace what you want in place of "Example".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using javascript only, you might try something like this:

```
<script>
    function show(){
    if(form.toggledisplay.checked == false){
        document.getElementById('example').style.display = "none";
    }
    else{
       document.getElementById('div').style.display = "block";
    }
 }
</script>

<form method = "POST" action="receipt.php" onsubmit="show()">
<textarea name = "comment"></textarea><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="toggledisplay" id="checkbox" value = "1"  >Show this comment in receipt<br>
<input type = "submit" value = "Print">
</form>
<div id="example" style="display:none;">This is the div you want to show</div>
```

If you are populating the contents of the `div` from the *receipt.php* file, you could make a post request to it, when the `onsubmit()` function is fired and fill the contents of the div like:

```
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML = "Result from the get/post request"
```

Hope this points you in the right direction.